# I/O based Selenium and multi-threading -- Running multiple tabs simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

I'm really new to selenium and the concept of threading and have been stuck for a week now.

Say I have 2 functions: `open_tabs` and `automate`

Using multi-threading, how do I get `automate` to start right after one of the tabs have successfully called the `open_tabs` function?

Open to any other suggestions as well!

Have been receiving this error after running the `automate` function:

*selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".collapsed"}*

```
urls = [list of urls]

def open_tabs(driver, url):

    driver.execute_script("window.open('{}');".format(url))

def automate(driver, handle):

        driver.switch_to.window(handle)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'collapsed')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)
        button.click()

        time.sleep(3)

for url in urls:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=open_tabs, args=(driver, url))
    t1.start()
    t1.join()

for handle in handles:
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=automate, args=(driver, handle))
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: I think you cant open multiple tabs and interact them with threading at same time, because only one tab is active on browser. You can open other driver and solve it

Comment: I've tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work for this platform as each login has a unique session id and opening multiple browsers returns an error page.